Problem with Chopper Opamps Gain
I am simulating the open-loop gain of a chopper opamp. The schematic is shown below. The chopper opamp consists of an input chopper, a single-stage op, and an output chopper.

I ran both the AC and Periodic AC simulations, and these were the simulation results. The simulation results were taken at VO_GM1, shown in the red circuit in the top figure.
AC Simulation = Red Curve.
PAC Simulation = Blue Curve.
The chopping frequency is 1 MHz. The load capacitance is taken to be 1 pF.
Could you please show me why the opamp behaves poorly at PAC simulation? There was no gain at dc at all.

Thank you all very much
